# Is there any invariance under the inversion mapping?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, invariance, inversive-geometry

[In geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion), there is a transformation called the inversion mapping which maps nonorthogonal circles into nonorthogonal lines and vice versa.(If I make a mistake, inform me, since I am not very familiar with the terminology)And my question is:

> Is there a magnitude of graphs that is preserved by the inversion mapping?

I cannot find one; I know there is a magnitude called the *ratio* which is preserved by projective transformations, is the *ratio* the thing I want?
Any help is well appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Angles are preserved.

Comment: @user6312, thanks, and how about the ratio, or how does it change the area, maybe I am not asking a good question here, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cross-ratio is preserved: if $A,B,C,D$ are points in the plane (not necessarily lying on a line) then
$$\frac{|AB||CD|}{|AC||BD|}$$
is preserved.

Also the sum of the angles at $A$ and $C$ in a quadrilateral $ABCD$ is preserved.

These two properties are combined into one:
if you see your plane as the complex plane, so that $A,B,C,D$ become complex numbers, then the complex cross-ratio  $(A-B)(C-D)/((A-C)(B-D))$ is (unfortunately not preserved, but) complex conjugated by inversion.

(area is not preserved; as noted by user6312 in the comments, angles between intersecting curves are preserved)

Comment: C'est magnifique! And especially the part of the view point of the complex plane is really astonishing; maybe it seems trivial to you, but I am not familiar with geometry so that it requires more elaborations; and I will look it up in other contexts, and all in all, thanks very much.